# parent / child method overriding

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, object-model

Consider the two below **concrete** classes:

```
public class A {
  protected void foo() {        
    System.out.println("A foo");
    bar();
  }

  protected void bar() {
    System.out.println("A bar");
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  @Override
  protected void foo() {
    super.foo();    
    System.out.println("B foo");
  }

  @Override
  protected void bar() {
    System.out.println("B bar");
  }
}


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.foo();
  }
}
```

The output will be:

```
A foo
B bar
B foo
```

Which is **correct**. But what if we need the result to be:

```
A foo
A bar
B foo
```

We **have to** override both methods.

Is there any solution for this in Java Object model?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You *must* override both methods, but you want the output shown in your 2nd example? Couldnt you just call `super.bar()` instead of putting a print statement when you override?

Comment: Print statements are just examples. In the real case it would includes more statements than just some prints.

Answer (score 3):

You should use composition instead of inheritance.
for example

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(new A());
        b.foo();
    }
}

class A implements Parent {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A foo");
        bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("A bar");
    }
}


interface Parent {
    void foo();
    void bar();
}

class B implements Parent {

Parent wrapped;

public B(Parent p) {
    this.wrapped = p;
}

@Override
public void foo() {
    wrapped.foo();
    System.out.println("B foo");
}

@Override
public void bar() {
    System.out.println("B bar");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a private `internalBar()` method from `A.foo()`, instead of calling the overridable `bar()`. The `A.bar()` method can also call `internalBar()` by default (to avoid code duplication), and still be overridden in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If execution of `bar()` in class `B` is not a problem you can use `super.bar()` inside it.